# Как установить две CMS на один домен?

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess, cms, dle, настройка

есть сайт под управлением DLE, есть скрипт (отдельный от DLE). установил скрипт в папку(monitoring) на том же домене, что и сайт DLE.

2 дня уже вожусь((

проблема в том, что DLE перехватывает запросы скрипта т.е

если я перехожу по *site.ru/monitoring/* открывается страница скрипта, пытаюсь авторизоваться, меня перенаправляет на *http://site.ru/cabinet/*

DLE пишет, что такой страницы нет))

авторизация в том скрипте проходит успешно.

подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему, чтобы скрипт работал как отдельный сайт, только из папки monitoring?

о том, что можно установить на отдельный домен/поддомен я знаю, нужно именно в папку.

**Спасибо за внимание**

**код .htaccess скрипта**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#Вызов страницы 404
ErrorDocument 404 /?404
#Динамические страницы
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+).htm$ /?module=pages&url=$1 [L]
#Сброс пароля
RewriteRule ^confirm/([^/]+)/$ /?module=password_reset&confirm=$1 [L]
#Каптча
RewriteRule ^captcha/?$ /?module=captcha [L]
#Листинг
RewriteRule ^listing/?$ /?module=listing [L]
#API
RewriteRule ^api/?$ /?module=api [L]
#Поиск
RewriteRule ^search/?$ /?module=search [L]
#Авторизация, регистрация и тд.
RewriteRule ^account/([a-z]+)/?$ ?module=account&action=$1 [L]
#Банлист
RewriteRule ^banlist/?$ ?module=banlist [L]
#Кабинет
RewriteRule ^cabinet/?$ ?module=cabinet [L]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/([a-z]+)/?$ /?module=cabinet&action=$1 [L]
#Страница сервера
RewriteRule ^servers/([0-9.:]*)/([a-z]+)/?$ /?module=servers&ip=$1&action=$2 [L]
#Модуль принятия оплаты
RewriteRule ^payment_gateway/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)?/$ /?module=payment_gateway&gateway=$1&action=$2 [L]
#Админка
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/$ /?module=admin_$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ /?module=admin_$1&section=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /?module=admin_$1&section=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9a-z_]+)/?$ /?module=admin_$1&section=$2&subsection=$3 [L]
```

**код .htaccess DLE**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Редиректы

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)(/?)$ index.php?cstart=$1 [L]

# Сам пост
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),(.*).html$ index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&cstart=$5&news_name=$6&seourl=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$ index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/print:page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$ engine/print.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*).html$ index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_name=$4&seourl=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$4&news_page=$2&cstart=$3&seourl=$5&seocat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$2&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ engine/print.php?news_page=$2&newsid=$3&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$1&cstart=$2&seourl=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ engine/print.php?news_page=$1&newsid=$2&seourl=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ index.php?newsid=$1&seourl=$2 [L]

# За день
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&cstart=$4 [L]
# За весь месяц
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&cstart=$3 [L]
# Вывод за весь год
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?year=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# вывод отдельному тегу
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?do=tags&tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=tags&tag=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# поиск по доп полям
RewriteRule ^xfsearch/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^xfsearch/(.*)/?$ index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1 [L]
# вывод для отдельного юзера
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/news(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/news/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/news/rss.xml(/?)+$ engine/rss.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 [L]
# вывод всех последних новостей
RewriteRule ^lastnews(/?)+$ index.php?do=lastnews [L]
RewriteRule ^lastnews/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=lastnews&cstart=$1 [L]
# вывод в виде каталога
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?catalog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?catalog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?catalog=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
# вывод непрочитанных статей
RewriteRule ^newposts(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=newposts [L]
RewriteRule ^newposts/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?subaction=newposts&cstart=$1 [L]
# вывод избранных статей
RewriteRule ^favorites(/?)+$ index.php?do=favorites [L]
RewriteRule ^favorites/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=favorites&cstart=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^rules.html$ index.php?do=rules [L]
RewriteRule ^statistics.html$ index.php?do=stats [L]
#Start Search Torrent
RewriteRule ^search-pravo.html$ index.php?do=search_torrents [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents.html$ index.php?do=search_torrents_s [L]
# Rutor
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/rutor-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?rutor=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/rutor-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&rutor=GO [L]
# Riper
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/riper-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?riper=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/riper-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&riper=GO [L]
# Rutracker
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/rutracker-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?rutracker=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/rutracker-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&rutracker=GO [L]
# Nnm-club
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/nnm_club-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?nnm_club=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/nnm_club-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&nnm_club=GO [L]
# Kinozal
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/kinozal-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?kinozal=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/kinozal-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&kinozal=GO [L]
# Rgfootball
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/rgfootball-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?rgfootball=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/rgfootball-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&rgfootball=GO [L]
# Freerutor
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/freerutor-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?freerutor=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/freerutor-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&freerutor=GO [L]
# Megapeer
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/megapeer-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?megapeer=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/megapeer-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&megapeer=GO [L]
# Limetorrents
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/limetorrents-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?limetorrents=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/limetorrents-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&limetorrents=GO [L]
# Toloka
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/toloka-([0-9]+)/start(/?)+$ /engine/modules/search-torrents/download.php?toloka=$1&download_search=on [L]
RewriteRule ^search-torrents/download/toloka-([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=search_torrents_down&id_tor=$1&toloka=GO [L]
#Stop Search Torrent    





RewriteRule ^addnews.html$ index.php?do=addnews [L]
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ engine/rss.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ uploads/sitemap.xml [L]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1&cstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/rss.xml$ engine/rss.php?do=cat&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page,([0-9]+),([^/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^print:([^/]+).html$ engine/print.php?do=static&page=$1&seourl=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ index.php?do=static&page=$1&seourl=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл .htaccess DLE который в корне сайта. В самое начало этого файла добавить

```
RewriteRule ^(pages|confirm|captcha|listing|api|search|account|banlist|cabinet|servers|payment_gateway|admin_[^/]+)(/.*)?$ /monitoring/$0 [L]
```

в .htaccess того скрипта

```
RewriteEngine On

#Вызов страницы 404
ErrorDocument 404 /monitoring/?404
#Динамические страницы
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+).htm$ ?module=pages&url=$1 [L]
#Сброс пароля
RewriteRule ^confirm/([^/]+)/$ ?module=password_reset&confirm=$1 [L]
#Каптча
RewriteRule ^captcha/?$ ?module=captcha [L]
#Листинг
RewriteRule ^listing/?$ ?module=listing [L]
#API
RewriteRule ^api/?$ ?module=api [L]
#Поиск
RewriteRule ^search/?$ ?module=search [L]
#Авторизация, регистрация и тд.
RewriteRule ^account/([a-z]+)/?$ ?module=account&action=$1 [L]
#Банлист
RewriteRule ^banlist/?$ ?module=banlist [L]
#Кабинет
RewriteRule ^cabinet/?$ ?module=cabinet [L]
RewriteRule ^cabinet/([a-z]+)/?$ ?module=cabinet&action=$1 [L]
#Страница сервера
RewriteRule ^servers/([0-9.:]*)/([a-z]+)/?$ ?module=servers&ip=$1&action=$2 [L]
#Модуль принятия оплаты
RewriteRule ^payment_gateway/([a-z]*)/([a-z]*)?/$ ?module=payment_gateway&gateway=$1&action=$2 [L]
#Админка
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/$ ?module=admin_$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ ?module=admin_$1&section=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ?module=admin_$1&section=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin_([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9a-z_]+)/?$ ?module=admin_$1&section=$2&subsection=$3 [L]
```